# RSSI max or min value of blue tooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, rssi

When initiate bluetooth device discovery and get the RSSI value, what would be the max or min device? I want to show a relative representation so users  know roughly speaking if they are far or close? So I need a point of reference

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you must identify. There is no absolute MAX or MIN value for the received power and it depends on the hardware of each device. What you can do to have an estimate in high level is to calculate the distance from the Device based on a propagation model such as Free Space Loss (which may differs a lot from the reality) which will be calculated based on the measured RSSI. Then having in mind that the Bluetooth's naming range is approximately 10m, you can set a close or far at your application.

Comment: Range depends on the class of the sender and can reach up too 100m for a class 1 device